Is there an option to use nginx instead of traefik?
The "Select a front-end web server/proxy to use" option seems to be gone. I'm using cookiecutter-django's docker compose setup.
I'd rather use nginx (a more familiar technology without the excessive abstractions of traefik).

Seems the option is gone.
PR #1282 from 2017 switched from Nginx to Caddy.
PR #1714 from 2019 switched Caddy to Traefik.
I'm pretty certain you can still configure any reverse proxy you like by hand.
